# IndexError: string index out of range - I cannot find answer anywhere but seems so easy

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I'm using python 3.4

I have a .txt file and each line starts with an id number, then is followed by letters and numbers, for example...

```
012394  The big Project 1997 June Terry Smith
013894  Toms Project   1994 March Michaal Bach
```

and so on... I need to copy all lines that start with 01 to another file

when I use the following it keeps giving me the above error:

```
with open("old.txt","r") as mf, open("new.txt","w") as nf:

    def dafunction():
        mf = open ("old.txt", "r")
        nf = open("new.txt","w")
        for line in mf:
            bat = str(line)
            if bat.startswith(01):
                nf.write(line)



dafunction()
mf.close()
nf.close()
```

I've tried using bat.startswith("01) and skipping setting bat variable and going straight to line.startswith(01), etc. and I keep getting the error.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? or another way to accomplish objective?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Why do you define a function while the files are open, then close the files and call the function, which itself opens (and fails to close) the files? Please provide the full error traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of unnecessary code. Try:

```
with open("old.txt") as mf, open("new.txt", "w") as nf:
    for line in mf:
        if line.startswith('01'):
            nf.write(line)
```

Comment: I've tried using the above format, and it appears what's happening is it always returns false.  I've tried using 'if line[1] == "1"' and all kinds of comparisons but no matter what, if I'm comparing it to 'line' or 'str(line)' it returns false? Any insight? And actually 'line[x]' always returns an error "out of range"

Comment: What do you mean *"returns false"*? You could try `line.strip().startswith('01')` to remove any whitespace at the start and end of the line before checking for `'01'`.

Comment: Thanks again for the help, by "returns false" I mean the `if` statement does not evaluate as `True` and perform the `nf.write(line)`, however if I put an `else` statement that says `else: nf.write("fml")` it will write "fml" for every line.  I tried adding `strip()`, same problem, it just never finds the `startswith('01')` as equal, or True, on the 'line' from the open "old.txt", no matter how I structure the argument?

Comment: @user3713209 `"012394  The big Project 1997 June Terry Smith".startswith('01')` gives me `True` in IDLE, as I'd expect. You need to look into your text file in more detail - try adding `print(line)` to ensure you're getting what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
if bat.startswith(01): is not correct python syntax, you cannot use an `int`
```

You should just open your files inside the function.

```
def dafunction():
    with open("old.txt","r") as mf:
        with open("new.txt","w") as nf:
            for line in mf:
                if line.startswith("01"): 
                    nf.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok yall, thanks for your help, you really helped me clean up my code, but it appears the problem was that the text file was saved from excel as unicode txt file and apparently the IDLE or python or whatever doesn't work well with unicode and it won't accurately compare without some other conversion code or something I guess.

I had the file saved as just txt tab delimited and then ran the code and it worked great!  Thanks again for yall's help and I hope someone else gets some use from this sometime in the future!

tl:dr - File was saved in unicode and that was causing the problem.